# How can I make typeahead fill in my searchbar with custom params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I installed 'twitter-typeahead-rails' into my app and set it up so that when I begin to type into a search box, suggestions drop down. Then when I click on the suggestions, the search box is filled in. But right now, it gets filled in with the displayKey, as in the html that defines the suggestions:

```
<div class='typeahead-name' id='<user.name>'><user.name></div>
```

How can I get it to fill in the searchbar with only `user.name`?

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
```

**typeahead-ified searchbox**

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id:"typeahead" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // initialize bloodhound engine
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
      datumTokenizer: function (d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
      },
      queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
      // sends ajax request to /typeahead/%QUERY
      // where %QUERY is user input
      remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY',
    });
    bloodhound.initialize();
    // initialize typeahead widget and hook it up to bloodhound engine
    // #typeahead is just a text input
    $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
      displayKey: function(user) {
        return "<div class='typeahead-name' id='" + user.name + "'>" + user.name + "</div>";
      },
      source: bloodhound.ttAdapter(),
    });
  });
</script>
```

**routes**

```
get 'typeahead/:query' => 'users#typeahead'
```

**users__controller.rb**

```
def typeahead
  q = params[:query]
  render json: User.where('name like ?, "%#{q}%")
end
```

Comment: doesn't `displayKey` already solve it ? Unless I understood the question wrong

Comment: No, displayKey sets the html that will be rendered in the suggestion menu that drops down. But when I click on a suggestion, the search bar is just filled in with that same raw html. I want to fill it in with simply `user.name`.

Comment: suggestions are dropdown items that are rendered based on a template like [this](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1031#issuecomment-66567928). `displayKey` is the one that is rendered in the textbox after something is selected from the dropdown

Comment: Then how can I separately define the html I want in the dropdown? That's what is currently defined in the displayKey, and it renders as expected.

Comment: is this exactly what you want ?? http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/11/

Comment: It is! Thanks, I'll play around with it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla It works! If you add it as an answer I could give you rep :)

Comment: I am glad it helped. Yeah, I actually want to add an answer because I'm trying to solve all the questions based on typeahead here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom suggestions can be added like below as per the [docs here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1031#issuecomment-66567928)

```
templates: {
    suggestion: function (data) {
        return '<p><strong>' + data.value + '</strong> - ' + data.year + '</p>';
    }
}
```

These are the dropdown items that are rendered. `displayKey` is the one that is rendered in the textbox after something is selected from the dropdown.

A displayKey can be rendered like this

```
displayKey: function(state){
  return 'Selected is ' + state.val;
}
```

Here is a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/pegp21r7/11/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Stumbling across your answer from a google search saved me a bunch of time :)